# Jasper sub report border line not covering all tuple height

Tags: jasper-reports

All Works fine but, rows margin do not cover all height. as shown in attached these two pictures.

*How I am doing*: I put rectangle in detail band, than sub report and other fields. on all fields, sub-report and rectangle i also apply `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject` and `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` for warping up the text which works fine. I am facing this problem still unresolved.

*As per my understanding*: sub-Report fields are also `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject` but didn't detect or get stretched of its main-report column. while if sub-report need extra space it will show properly. I have tried almost every thing available in iReport-Designer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop figures. Use borders, preferably via report styles.

Comment: Would you please explain a bit?

Comment: If all you need is borders, then you should not use figures, but the Padding and Borders property, which you can specify for a Report style and then apply it to any number of elements. Jasper report styles work just like CSS styles - I am sure you will find yourself right at home. To create a style in iReport go to the report Styles section, right click and add a new style, then specify whatever border you like for it in its properties section and apply it to any report elements.

Comment: I am doing in the same way, by setting *Padding and Borders* property

Comment: Then just remove figures from your report.

Comment: I am not using figures